# does the order of my node js matter on how I process server.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm learning node js application, and I was wondering if it matters which order I put my error handlers for my app.use (404 and 500 error) and controllers routes for my app.get(/) route?

https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs/index.htm

here's my app.js

```
//**** DEPENDENCIES ****//
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

//use the express handlebars
const exphbs  = require('express-handlebars');
app.engine('handlebars', exphbs({defaultLayout: 'main'}));
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');


const index = require('./controllers/index');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');



//**** MIDDLEWARE ****//
// static files will live in the public folder
app.use(express.static('public'));


// **** CONTROLLERS **** //
// separate the route from the app.js to make it cleaner
require('./controllers/index.js')(app);

//app.get('/', index)

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  const err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  if(err.status == 404) {
    res.status(err.status || 404);
    res.render('error', {err : err.status, message: "Sorry We Can't Help You", stack: err.stack });
  } else if (err.status == 500) {
    console.log(500);
    // render the error page
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {err : err.status});
    // res.redirect('/500.html');
  }
});


// **** Local server Port **** //
var PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.listen(PORT, function(req, res) {
  console.log("Express App listening on port " + PORT + "...");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your specific case, the order does matter because you're calling `next(err)` in your 404 handler and you want your custom error route handler to get that and the only way for it to get that `next(err)` is for it to be afterwards.  If you reversed the order, then you'd end up only with the default error handler in Express, not your own custom error handler.

So, for the way you've written the code, you have the correct order and the reverse order would not do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, though I can't find it in the express documentation. The route matching algorithm looks in order and executes each that match in order until one calls res.end() (often via other methods like res.render() and res.send())

Comment: This is not what really what the OP is asking.  They are asking about the order of only two specific types of error handlers.  Also, it isn't `res.end()` or `res.send()` that stops routing.  It's the lack of calling `next()`.